# Examples of Substrate Benchmarking

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

I am looking to learn to benchmark. Except for the official documentation, I did not find much information/examples.

Can you please help me with examples/articles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> the official documentation

Seems like a pretty good place to learn about benchmarking to me:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/benchmarking

Beyond that:

- 3 Hour Video on Benchmarking: https://youtu.be/Qa6sTyUqgek
- Nearly every pallet in FRAME folder has some benchmarks you can use as reference:

  - https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame